# Rvalue переменная

Tags: c++

В одной из книжек по С++ прочитал такое:

```
double a = 8.1;
double && b = 3.2;
double && c = 3*a-4;
double && d = func(c);
```

В чем разница между 1 и 2 строкой?

С 3-ей ясно: после вычисления выражения мы получим число, которое будет скопировано, если записать так:

```
double c = 3*a-4;
```

Используя `&&` мы предотвращаем копирования.

4-ая строка подобная 3: после выполнения функции произойдет копирования, если убрать `&&`.

Comment: [Вот здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-double-ampersand-mean-in-c11) расписывают подробно и с разными ссылками.

Можно еще много чего в гугле по запросу

     c++ && reference

найти.

Comment: @avp я так и не понял разницу между 1 и 2 строкой. Мне кажется, что копирования здесь происходить не будет, и  автор показал то, что так писать можно и ошибок не возникнет. Чтобы не усложнять разные проверки на этапе компиляции, разработчики языка дали возможность писать так
`double a = 2.1`
 и так 
`double && a = 2.1`

Comment: @andreyk, если откровенно, то чем дальше, тем больше С++ начинает казаться мне инструментом для любителей головоломок, а не языком для практического программирования.

Comment: @avp: идея rvalue reference сама по себе, в отрыве от её реализации в C++, не так уж и плоха: если вам передаётся объект, который точно собирается умереть, то можно «разобрать» его на куски и использовать их вместо того, чтобы скопировать данные только для того, чтобы оригинал был тут же уничтожен. Но протягивать эту семантику на уровень базовых конструкций языка...

Comment: @VladD, конечно, это верно. 

В [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml), руководствуясь декларацией


     C++ is a huge language with many advanced features. In some cases we constrain, or even ban, use of certain features




и рассмотрев все [Pros и Cons](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Rvalue_references) все же пишут:

     Do not use rvalue references

Answer (score 6):

Разница между 1-й и 2-й строками в том, что в первой строке создаётся переменная типа `double`, а во второй создаётся rvalue-ссылка на временный объект типа `double`. В данном случае время жизни этого временного объекта продлевается на время жизни ссылки. 
Этот пример не интересен и поэтому его сложно понять. Давайте разберём более интересный пример. Пусть у нас есть следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A() = default;
    A(const A& other)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy ctor\n";
    }

    A(A&& other)
    {
        std::cout << "Move ctor\n";
    }
};

void first(A a)
{
    //...
}

void second(A&& a)
{
    //...
}


int main()
{
    first(A{});
    std::cout << "Let's call the second:\n";
    second(A{});
    return 0;
}
```

Он выведет следующее:

```
Move ctor
Let's call the second:
```

Как вы можете видеть, имея вызов первой функции нам пришлось задейстовать конструктор перемещения, когда мы передали наш временный объект функции `first()`. Если бы у нас не было конструктора перемещения, то вызван бы был конструктор копирования.

Во втором же случае, мы имеем ссылку и вызова конструктора копирования/перемещения не происходит, что в некотоых случаях может значительно ускорить код.

На деле `T&&` используется для перегрузки функций(не только, но для начального понимания достаточно), чтобы различать, какая функция была вызвана с аргументом, являющимся временным объектом, а какая была вызвана с постоянным, lvalue-объектом. Для чего? Причина проста, если мы имеем временный объект, мы можем делать с ним всё, что угодно. С lavalue-объектом, как правило, нужно обращаться бережно.
К примеру:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A() = default;
    void setName(const std::string& name)
    {
        std::cout << "Called setName with lvalue.\n";
        m_Name = name;
    }

    void setName(std::string&& name)
    {
        std::cout << "Called setName with rvalue.\n";
        m_Name = std::move(name);
    }
private:
    std::string m_Name;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::string name{"another name"};
    a.setName("New name");//№1
    a.setName(name);//№2
    return 0;
}
```

Выведет:

```
Called setName with rvalue.
Called setName with lvalue.
```

Как вы можете видеть, мы получили два разных вызова, которые зависит от типа выражения, переданного в качестве аргумента функции. И тогда, когда мы вызываем `setName(std::string&& name)` мы не вызываем конструктор копирования, чтобы поместить стркоу в `m_Name`, но мы вызываем конструктор **перемещения**, для этого. Который может быть многократно более эффективным, чем конструктор копирования(зависит от длины строки, в большей степени)

Answer (score 3):

ixSci все верно описал, но все же можно объяснить и по-простому.
Стандарт С++, начиная с С++11, ввел rvalue-ссылки (раньше были только обычные ссылки, T&, которые теперь называют lvalue-ссылки).

Предварительно стоит сказать, что, говоря очень упрощенно - с точки зрения языка C++ любое выражение можно рассматривать как lvalue (у выражения можно взять адрес, например, `Object obj;` - можно взять адрес obj) , либо как rvalue (остальные случаи, например, любой литерал: `10; "mama";`).

И rvalue-ссылки, и lvalue-ссылки все еще остаются ссылками, а значит должны инициализироваться при создании. При этом rvalue-ссылки могут быть связаны только с rvalue (в отличие от lvalue-ссылок, которые могут быть связаны как с lvalue, так и с rvalue - когда ссылка объявлена как const T&).

Таким образом, получаем:

```
double a = 8.1;            // переменная типа double
double && b = 3.2;         // rvalue-ссылка на временный объект
double && c = 3*a-4;       // rvalue-ссылка на временный объект
double && d = func(c);     // rvalue-ссылка на временный объект
```

Вывод:

> В чем разница между 1 и 2 строкой?

"a" и "b" - переменные разных типов, с несколько различным механизмом создания.

Если бы вместо double использовался какой-нибудь пользовательский класс, то использование rvalue-ссылок позволило бы написать более оптимальный код, позволило бы использовать move-семантику и perfect-forwarding, но это уже предмет другого вопроса.